# どのような多面体かを知るコード

Tags: アルゴリズム, グラフ理論

多面体を作る方法について

PythonでもCでもMatlabでも言語は問いません。

例えば正20面体に関する以下のようなデータがあるとします。
このデータは正20面体の各頂点0から11に関してどの3点でひとつの三角形、つまり正20面体のひとつの面を作っているかを示します。
この画像のように頂点をつなげていくことができます
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
データ1

```
6 4 0 
4 9 0 
9 3 0 
3 11 0 
11 6 0
4 6 1 
6 8 1 
8 2 1 
2 10 1 
10 4 1 
8 7 2 
7 5 2 
5 10 2 
10 9 4 
9 10 5 
7 11 3 
5 7 3 
9 5 3 
11 8 6 
8 11 7
```

私はこのような形式のデータから多面体がどのような形をしているかがわかる、コードを探しています。
上のようなデータであれば自明かもしれませんが下のように複雑なデータになればすぐにはわからないと思います。
データ2

```
14 0 12 
13 14 12 
13 6 14 
12 4 13 
12 0 15 
16 12 15 
16 4 12 
15 9 16 
15 0 17 
18 15 17 
18 9 15 
17 3 18 
17 0 19 
20 17 19
20 3 17 
19 11 20 
19 0 14 
21 19 14 
21 11 19 
14 6 21 
23 1 22 
13 23 22 
13 4 23 
22 6 13 
22 1 24 
25 22 24 
25 6 22 
24 8 25 
24 1 26 
27 24 26 
27 8 24 
26 2 27 
26 1 28 
29 26 28 
29 2 26 
28 10 29 
28 1 23 
30 28 23 
30 10 28 
23 4 30
27 2 31 
32 27 31 
32 8 27 
31 7 32 
31 2 33 
34 31 33 
34 7 31 
33 5 34 
33 2 29 
35 33 29 
35 5 33 
29 10 35 
30 4 16 
36 30 16 
36 10 30 
16 9 36 
37 5 35 
36 37 35 
36 9 37 
35 10 36 
39 3 20 
38 39 20 
38 7 39 
20 11 38 
40 3 39 
34 40 39 
34 5 40 
39 7 34 
18 3 40 
37 18 40 
37 9 18 
40 5 37 
21 6 25 
41 21 25 
41 11 21 
25 8 41 
32 7 38 
41 32 38 
41 8 32 
38 11 41
```

私が実現したいこと達成するためのコードをご存じの方がいらっしゃったら教えてください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/146328

Comment: こちらの質問がオフトピックとして[クローズされました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)が、個人的になぜクローズされたのか疑問であったため、このサイトの使い方について質問できるメタというサイトでこのことについて質問してみました： https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2755/19110

Comment: ここまでのディスカッションをチャットへ移動しました。 https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83523/discussion-on-question-by--

Answer (score 5):

この質問は、`Graph`で扱える問題です。`Graph`にはいろいろありますが、ウィキペディア日本語版では[「グラフ (データ構造)」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95_(%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0))の`Graph`です。

以下に、Pythonの`NetworkX`を使ったサンプルコードとその結果を書いておきます。

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

s = '''
14 0 12 
13 14 12 
13 6 14 
12 4 13 
12 0 15 
16 12 15 
16 4 12 
15 9 16 
15 0 17 
18 15 17 
18 9 15 
17 3 18 
17 0 19 
20 17 19
20 3 17 
19 11 20 
19 0 14 
21 19 14 
21 11 19 
14 6 21 
23 1 22 
13 23 22 
13 4 23 
22 6 13 
22 1 24 
25 22 24 
25 6 22 
24 8 25 
24 1 26 
27 24 26 
27 8 24 
26 2 27 
26 1 28 
29 26 28 
29 2 26 
28 10 29 
28 1 23 
30 28 23 
30 10 28 
23 4 30
27 2 31 
32 27 31 
32 8 27 
31 7 32 
31 2 33 
34 31 33 
34 7 31 
33 5 34 
33 2 29 
35 33 29 
35 5 33 
29 10 35 
30 4 16 
36 30 16 
36 10 30 
16 9 36 
37 5 35 
36 37 35 
36 9 37 
35 10 36 
39 3 20 
38 39 20 
38 7 39 
20 11 38 
40 3 39 
34 40 39 
34 5 40 
39 7 34 
18 3 40 
37 18 40 
37 9 18 
40 5 37 
21 6 25 
41 21 25 
41 11 21 
25 8 41 
32 7 38 
41 32 38 
41 8 32 
38 11 41
'''
data = np.fromstring(s, sep=" ").reshape(-1, 3)

G = nx.Graph()

# ノードの追加
nodes = np.unique(data)
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

# エッジの追加
for d in data:
    G.add_edges_from([(d[0], d[1]), (d[1], d[2]), (d[2], d[0])])

# レイアウトの取得
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# 可視化
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
plt.axis()
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

英語版 Wikipedia の [Graph drawing](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95_(%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0))には、`Graph drawing`のソフトウェアがたくさん紹介されているので、それらのソフトウェアを使った回答を書いてもらえるとうれしいです。

Comment: [コメントは、対象投稿に対する補足的な情報を付与するための「付箋」です。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)意見が分かれる論点に対するディスカッションは、こちらのチャットで続行しましょう: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83227/discussion-on-answer-by-yasuhiro-niji-  それがコミュニティとしてのどうあるべきか、というようなサイト自身のポリシーの話である場合は、 Meta を利用しましょう。